# Chrome DevTools makes tab memory steadily increase until it crashes

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome to run a page and it runs fine for hours on end, I can attest that no memory problems rise up when it's running by itself. Whenever I use DevTools to debug something, however, the tab's memory footprint only keeps increasing and increasing (as if there was a memory leak) to the point it just crashes when it reaches the point where Chrome kills a tab due to memory limit.

Some things I could figure out were that it happens if and only if DevTools panel is open (regardless of any options?), and it happens on pretty much any website (websites that load more stuff to memory tend to bloat faster). I also found out that, if the DevTools tab is closed, the memory usage sharply drops to normal usage (something like from 900mb to 200mb, which is what it would be without DevTools), and reopening makes the tab start to bloat again from scratch. I tried running the garbage collector forcibly on Performance tab, but it also didn't do anything. I don't know what causes this, but I also couldn't find anything that refers to this issue.
Any help in this matter is appreciated.

Comment: Devtools in Chrome is a huge memory hog for me as well.

Comment: And CPU too. I've seen a simple spinning SVG image absolutely KILL my CPU when devtools is open. In fact I had to disable it during development.

Comment: One thing I've been doing recently is unless I'm actively trying to diagnose network requests I've just turned off recording (it's Ctrl+E when the network tab is visible).